# Values not getting passed from javascript to codebehind asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp

```
    <div class="row">
                                <label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="text"><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
                                            onchange="javascript:updateHiddenField();"></asp:TextBox><asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1"
                                                runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                    <span>Find e-mail on <a href="#">My Address Book</a> / <a href="#">Contacts</a></span>
                                    <span>Find e-mail on 
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">Facebook Profile</asp:HyperLink></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Invite Type</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="inner-row">
                                        <asp:RadioButton  runat="server" ID="r1" Checked="true" GroupName="r" 
                                            />
                                        <label for="id-1"><em>Personalized</em> - Add a personal note to your invitation. This invite type will let your friend know of your identity and will include your personal note</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner-row">
                                        <asp:RadioButton  runat="server" ID="r2" GroupName="r"   />
                                        <label for="id-2"><em>Anonymous</em> - Sending an invite anonymously will not reveal your indentity to your friend.</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <label for="message">Personal Note</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="textarea">
                                        <div class="textarea-holder">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" 
                                                Columns="30"  onchange="javascript:updateHiddenField1();"></asp:TextBox><asp:HiddenField
                                                ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="text-note">Including a note is optional, but isn’t<br />personalized messages always nice :)</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" onClick="LinkButton6_Click" CssClass="btn-send"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This is my aspx code and i am trying to transfer values first from textbox then to hiddenfield and then codebehind

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateHiddenField() {
        document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = document.getElementById('TextBox2').value;

    }

    function updateHiddenField1() {
        document.getElementById('HiddenField2').value = document.getElementById('TextBox1').value
    }
</script>
```

Values are getting displayed when i do `alert(document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value);`

However they aren't passed to codebehind

```
 public void LinkButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 

 try{
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            mail.Subject = "";
            mail.Body = HiddenField1.Value;
            mail.To.Add(HiddenField2.Value);

            ////send the message

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("","");
            //mySmtpClient.Port="25";
            mySmtpClient.Host = "";
            mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mySmtpClient.Credentials = myCredential;
            mySmtpClient.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

[image]

EDIT:

1. I have tried using `mail.Body = TextBox2.Text;
           mail.To.Add(TextBox1.Text);`
2. I have tried without the UpdatePanel
3. The code is in the CSS popup that is the main issue

AS suggested i have used html button to call javascript function

```
  function btn_click() {
        var email = document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value;
        var body = document.getElementById('HiddenField2').value;

    }
```

How do i pass this value as my credentials in Asp.net

Please help

Comment: Why aren't you simply using the TextBox values in your codebehind?

Comment: i tried that it isnt working same error so tried using this same thing happens here as well

Comment: Is this in a UserControl or is there anything else that may not be obvious from your code samples?

Comment: @jrummell The only control I can think might cause the values to not be present upon submit would be `UpdatePanel`. However, in this case it seems the OP is using a link to submit, which won't work.

Comment: i have tried that as well inially wasnt using an Update panel

Comment: I would personally be asking the question "Why am I unable to read from a textbox control", rather than a `HiddenField`. Are you able to read from any control at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function SendForm() {

        var email = $get("TextBox2").value;
        var message = $get("TextBox1").value;

        PageMethods.SendForm(email, message,
   OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
    }

    function OnSucceeded() {
        // Dispaly "thank you."
        $get("ContactFieldset").innerHTML = "<p>Thank you!</p>";
    }

    function OnFailed(error) {
        // Alert user to the error.
        alert(error.get_message());
    }
</script>
```

and in Asp.net code behind use :

```
 [WebMethod]
public static void SendForm(string email, string message)
{


    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = "";
        mail.From = new MailAddress("");
        mail.Body = message;
        mail.To.Add(email);

        ////send the message

        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential myCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("","");
        //mySmtpClient.Port="25";
        mySmtpClient.Host = "";
        mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = myCredential;
        mySmtpClient.Send(mail);



    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
    {
        throw new Exception("You must supply an email address.");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    {
        throw new Exception("Please provide a message to send.");
    }

    // If we get this far we know that they entered enough data, so
    // here is where you would send the email or whatever you wanted
    // to do :)
}
```

This should be good for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to read the value direct from TextBox on codebehind?

```
mail.Body = TextBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're inputting the email address into TextBox2 and then copying it in to HiddenField1 but reading HiddenField2 for the address in code-behind. Similarly, you're inputting the mail body into TextBox1 and then copying it in to HiddenField2 but then reading HiddenField1 in code-behind *(this swapping between 1 and 2 on the client is needlessly confusing)*. When testing for values in the hidden fields, are you filling both textboxes with data?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think u should remove the hiddenfields and anything related to it (javascript functions). Focus on what is causing the problem not the solution, the problem is that the textbox values are not posted back to the server. When you eventually get it to work with the hidden field the problem might still exist. Although you already found out that hidden fields have the same problems as the original textboxes.

Isolating the problem:

1) Are the values actually posted to the server? (you can verify this with browser build in developer tools or a plugin like HttpWatch, in the worst case you can use a sniffer)

2) Make sure the updatepanels aren't interfering by turning off the ajax/updatepanel functionality. (you can do this by setting EnablePartialRendering to false on your ScriptManager, which is usually located on the masterpage). Although this shouldn't matter.

3) When you have verified that the correct values are actually posted to the server, make sure there is no strange logic in the Page_Load (or similar function) that overwrites the postback values which are processed right before OnLoad. This might be some initialization which should only run when it is not a post-back.

4) Make sure that the controls exist when the post-back variables are processed, otherwise the post-back values are ignored. You noticed that the code is in a "CSS popup" make sure that this popup exists (in the controls collection) when the post-back variables are processed.

Comment: I have stopped using asp.net button i am using a submit button instead 
'var email = document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value;
        var body = document.getElementById('HiddenField2').value;' is there a way of transferring this to smtp processing